# Prolog find indices in a list and output them as a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to implement a predicate `indices_zero(L,R)`, which should find all positions of zeros in a list and output the indices in a new list.
I'm trying to do this with accumulators.
For example:

```
?-indices_zero([1,-2,3,0,5,0],R).
R=[4,6];
```

I have implemented following:

```
indices_zero(Ls,R):-
   indices_zero(Ls,1,[],Result).

indices_zero([L|Ls],N,R,Result):- 
   L=:=0,
   N1 is N+1,
   indices-zero(Ls,N1,[N|R],Result).
indices_zero([L|Ls],N,R,Result):-
   L=\=0,
   N1 is N+1,
   indices_zero(Ls,N1,R,Result).
indizes_zero([],_,Result,Result).
```

I'm not sure why my implementation doesn't work. I think my thirst clause
isn't correct, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? Also it is `indices_zero` not `indices-zero`. Notice the `_` vs `-`. Also, `indices_zero(Ls,R):-indices_zero(Ls,1,[],Result).` notice one is `R` and the other is `Result`.

Comment: There are a lot of typos or errors in your listing. In the first clause, you have an argument `R` but using `Result` in the body. Both would be cited as singletons. Your last clause is spelled `indizes_zero` instead of `indices_zero`. Your second clause calls `indices-zero` instead of `indices_zero`.

Comment: I'm such an idiot:-( can't believe it!! thanks, thanks for all the answers!! trying to find the solution since hours but never  have been looking at my typing errors.

Comment: It's a good practice to chase down the error and warning messages. Your `R` versus `Result` issue would yield a warning about "singleton variable" which means you have a variable that only occurs once (and, therefore, appears to have no purpose). When executing the code, you might see an error that `indices-zero` is undefined, which would lead you to finding the misspelling.

Comment: You may like: `indices_zero(L,R) :- findall(I, nth1(I,L,0), R).` That's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
indices_zero(Ls, R) :-
    indices_zero(Ls, 1, [], R).

indices_zero([], _, Result, Result).

indices_zero([0|T], N, Result_in, Result_out) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    indices_zero(T, N1, [N|Result_in], Result_out).

indices_zero([H|T], N, Result_in, Result_out) :-
    H \== 0,
    N1 is N + 1,
    indices_zero(T, N1, Result_in, Result_out).

?- indices_zero([1,-2,3,0,5,0],R).
R = [6, 4] ;
false.
```

Here is a variation that builds the result while backtracking.
Notice the order of the indices in the answer are now in ascending order.

```
indices_zero(Ls,R) :-
    indices_zero(Ls,1,R).

indices_zero([],_,[]).

indices_zero([0|T], N, [N|Result]) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    indices_zero(T, N1, Result).

indices_zero([H|T], N, Result) :-
    H \== 0,
    N1 is N + 1,
    indices_zero(T, N1, Result).

?- indices_zero([1,-2,3,0,5,0],R).
R = [4, 6] ;
false.
```